# How to approach Android development in C# where the app will need internet access?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I will need to begin development on an Android applicaiton soon. This application will need to communicate with a server over the internet. I hope to be able to do my development in C# in one of the various development environments that appear to be available, e.g. Mono for Android.

My questions are:

- What is the best framework for developing C# applications for Android?
- What will give me the most flexibility for communicating over the Internet? (My boss tells me that existing c# --> Android frameworks have limitations regarding internet access)
- What are the limitations that I can expect to face doing this with C#?
- What are your experiences with taking this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For communication over internet there might be many ways, depends on your needs.
It can be HTTP requests with some POST data, or proper low-level communication over Sockets.

If you need to communicate with web service that accepts POST requests and provides some data in XML (for example), then you might use HTTP request way.

If you have real-time server that servers Sockets communication, then you might want to use Sockets with some data protocol over it (based on which data protocol server accepts / serves).

There is full support for establishing Sockets communication using MonoDroid with. It is almost the same as with x86 .Net implementation on Windows.